# Cosmos Query Latency

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

```
FeedResponse<T> feedResponse =
cosmosContainer.readMany(
    ids.stream()
        .map(id -> new CosmosItemIdentity(partitionKey, id))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()),
    domainClass);
```

The above cosmos piece is taking more than 1 sec, which is too much. Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: There's really not enough information to answer such a question. For instance: where is your code running: locally? In the same region as your Cosmos DB instance? A different region? Are you using direct/tcp or gateway/http? Etc. You'll need to edit your question to provide specifics.

Comment: Also: Please be mindful of tags. For example, you applied `cosmos` which, in its description, specifically says it's for Cosmos OS and unrelated to Cosmos DB. I removed this tag, along with others that really aren't necessary.

Comment: How many items are in `ids`? And why is 1 second too much? Where is this code running? Is it running from your machine or deployed somewhere in Azure on the same region as the Cosmos DB account? What is the P99 latency?

Answer (score -1):

The latency of the code block execution depends on a few factors like:

1. Where the code is being deployed: is it on your local machine or on Azure resources?
2. If the code is on Azure resources, make sure to check the region of execution because a few regions will run with some latency in unexpected situations.
3. Make sure to have the Cosmos DB created in the *same* region as that of execution. Latency will be high when the operation involves multiple regions.

Comment: fyi this doesn't really answer any question, as the OP hasn't provided any specifics, which I already asked for in a comment (and comments are where such suggestions would belong, not as an answer - the exact reason I posted as a comment, and not an answer, 2 days ago)